# wp_dropdown_pages() returns empty string for post type anything other then page

Tags: post-type

`wp_dropdown_pages()` while using for any post type other then `page` returns empty string. [Codex says](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_pages) post type can be passed as key also the function uses `get_pages()` which takes the `post_type` key. So, I don't see why it isn't working for me.

```
    $args = array(
        'echo' => 1,
        'name' => 'my_posts',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'show_option_none' => 'any'
    );
    $select = wp_dropdown_pages($args);
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the same codex page:

> With the 'post_type' parameter you can get a drop down of any post type, including custom post types, as long as the post type in question is hierarchical.

post != hierachical. That's the answer. :)

Comment: damn it! :) Memory recall, I knew that!!